# How to fix AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loc'(Pandas)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas script.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('sample.csv',delimiter=',')

def mapping(df):
     #work of data mapping
     for column_name, column in df.transpose().iterrows():
         df.rename(columns ={'first name' : 'FNAME', 'secret': 'CODE'}, inplace = True)
         df.rename(columns ={'alias' : 'FNAME', 'code': 'CODE'}, inplace = True)
         df.rename(columns ={'initial name' : 'FNAME', 'id': 'CODE'}, inplace = True)

final_df = mapping(data)

#If the code is greater than 12 digits, leave it blank
final_df.loc[final_df['CODE'].astype(str).str.len() >12, 'CODE']= ''
```

I'm getting the error as :

```
final_df.loc[final_df['CODE'].astype(str).str.len() >12, 'CODE']= ''
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

Any fixes for this?

Comment: check `type(final_df)` ? looks like the problem is in the function and when you call it over the dataframe `mapping(data)` returns `None` ?

Comment: when I return only mapping(data), it displays the data but when final_df = mapping(data) ,print(final_df) it returns None

Comment: What is result of `print(type(mapping(data)))`?

Comment: result is NoneType@anky

Comment: exactly, so `None` type cannot be assigned as a new dataframe. You should alter your function to return type `pd.DataFrame` and then your code would work.

Comment: I have edited the code please suggest how to return type pd.DataFrame

Comment: remove the `inplace=True` from each line. Change `df.rename(columns ={'first name' : 'FNAME', 'secret': 'CODE'}, inplace = True)` to `df=df.rename(columns ={'first name' : 'FNAME', 'secret': 'CODE'})` do this for all 3 lines(though you can club all renames together in a single dictionary) and add `return df` to the last line of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mapping` function does not return anything. So when you assign it to `final_df`, nothing would be assigned to it making it `None`.

You should add `return df` to the last line of your function to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the `final_df` variable is `None` (the function above returns actually `None` and the object `None` does not have indeed this attribute `loc`.

Make sure that this function `mapping` returns the object you want to actually return.

Comment: when I return only mapping(data), it displays the data but when final_df = mapping(data) ,print(final_df) it returns None

Comment: Your function mapping should return the actual object you just modified otherwise a function with no return statement returns, by default, `None`.